# Which Marvel Universe is this Doctor Strange from?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In the start of *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), we see the following Dr. Strange running and casting spells.

Which universe is this Dr. Strange from?

[image]

Comment: Technically the entire MCU takes place in Universe-199999

Comment: @Valorum I very much doubt [collections of] multiverses are being numbered.  Thus I suspect "entire" is the point where this bold statement breaks down.  If 199999 is live action 616 main MCU continuity (Explicitly per Dr. Strange 2's Christine Palmer and less so by cosmic coincidence in Spider-Man 2's Quentin Beck - neither of which are authoritative but no one is challenging it in-universe) then it seems reasonable that live action MCU 617 would be designated 200000 in the bigger picture multiverse.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Well there's the rub. 616 is the comic continuity. And it can't be that because a bunch of people who are VIPs just died horribly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Copied from [my own answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/117955/1190) to the same question from a sister site.

He is referred to as Defender Strange by fans and media also Defender Strange's outfit is a reference to Doctor Strange's appearance in [2012's Defenders comic series](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Defenders_Vol_4).

For which earth it belongs to, Raimi himself revealed it:

> On the film's audio commentary, Raimi revealed that the gray-templed Stephen Strange variant hails from Earth-617, the multiversal next-door neighbor of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, which is set on Earth-616. - [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/multiverse-of-madness-defender-stranger-earth-617-mcu/)

Comment: The official subtitles also identify him as "Defender Strange".

Comment: Per my objection to the question, the entire MCU takes place in Universe-199999.

Comment: @Valorum That doesn't seem to be considered canon by recent MCU writers; see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265365/which-universe-designation-is-the-mcu-using

Comment: @Valorum, technically, I think of it as MCM (multiverse, obv) 199999 and *within that multiverse*, is Universe 616 and the others, and the comics 616 is part of a different multiverse entirely. Multimultiverses. M^2.