# Do all the What If universes from the MCU have official designations?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-what-if-2021

The MCU is set in Earth-199999, and in the comics:

> "Marvel has given several What If stories official numerical designations to make them contiguous with the Marvel Multiverse and differentiate them from the main Marvel Universe of Earth-616.[citation needed]"
> – [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_If_(comics)#:%7E:text=Marvel%20has%20given%20several%20What%20If%20stories%20official%20numerical%20designations%20to%20make%20them%20contiguous%20with%20the%20Marvel%20Multiverse%20and%20differentiate%20them%20from%20the%20main%20Marvel%20Universe%20of%20Earth%2D616.%5Bcitation%20needed%5D)

Do the alternative universes in the Disney+ anthology also have designations, or are they considered part of Earth-199999 somehow?

Comment: [Citation needed] = "Someone made this up"

Comment: @Valorum if you look through that article you'll see examples with multiversal designations, for the What If universes, for instance Earth-717

Comment: [Citation needed](https://xkcd.com/285/)

Comment: The way I see it, if the story deviated from another one, it would make sense to give it a different designation; although it's not guaranteed that they did give one explicitly.

Comment: @Clockwork hence my question

Comment: Given that [the designation Earth-199999 was contradicted in one of the movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/265365/21430), this is likely to fall into "depends who you ask" territory.

Comment: @IMSoP more like, one of the many movies

Comment: @MerajalMaksud I'm not sure what you mean. Yes, there are many movies; at least one of them has mentioned Earth-616; to my knowledge, none has confirmed Earth-199999.

Answer (score -1):

The first season of What If? has already designated each new universe in the show except Gamora's. And for Earth-199999 becoming Earth-616, I'd say all these "MCU" Earths are 199999 up until the specific, crucial moments that change the timelines; the Earth-616 version of Earth-199999 is the timeline where they "defeated" Thanos. And with the events of Loki Season 2, Earth-616 is now just another Earth.

Comment: Is this just your own guess or can you provide any evidence for it?